# C++ Using Constructors from CRTP Template-Template Base Class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, using, template-templates

What is the syntax for inheriting constructors from a [curiously recursing template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) template-template base class?

```
template<typename T, template<typename> typename U>
struct Base {
    Base(int) { }
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T, Derived> {
    using Base<T, Derived>::Base;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Derived<double> foo(4);
    return 0;
}
```

In VS2019, the above code results in the following errors:

> error C3210: 'Base<double, Derived<double> >': a member using-declaration can only be applied to a base class member
>   error C3881: can only inherit constructor from direct base

What is the syntax required to get the above code to work?

Comment: "*What is [redacted] required to get the above code to work?*" - `C++17` compiler that's not MSVS, as it [appears](https://godbolt.org/z/fQvpFf).

Comment: @Fureeish I was afraid that might be the answer.  Hopefully someone can come up with a work-around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is valid code and it [does compile with GCC 9.2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/R1Odrk). Try a newer version of your compiler or a different compiler. Or contact with your implementer.

Until then, here is a workaround that [does compile with MSVC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/U9fXcv) now:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> typename U>
struct Base {
    Base(int) { }
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived;

template<typename T>
using Base_type = Base<T, Derived>;

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base_type<T> {
    using Base_type<T>::Base;
};

int main() {
    Derived<double> foo(4);
    return 0;
}
```